# "the geoip2 module requires the maxminddb library" but the library is installed

Tags: compiling, configure

I am trying to compile `nginx` with a module: https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module. Before the nginx compilation, this library: https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb needs to be installed. I followed the instructions (https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb/blob/master/README.md#installing-from-a-tarball), compiled and installed the library. After the installation, `ldconfig -p | grep maxminddb` gives:

```
libmaxminddb.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmaxminddb.so.0
libmaxminddb.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmaxminddb.so
```

However, when I configure nginx with ngx_http_geoip2_module, it complains during configure:

```
adding module in /home/cilium/ngx_http_geoip2_module
checking for MaxmindDB library ... not found
./configure: error: the geoip2 module requires the maxminddb library.
```

which is exactly the library I've already installed. This error seems to come from the `config` file of `ngx_http_geoip2_module`:

```
ngx_feature="MaxmindDB library"
ngx_feature_name=
ngx_feature_run=no
ngx_feature_incs="#include <maxminddb.h>"
ngx_feature_libs=-lmaxminddb
. auto/feature

if [ $ngx_found = yes ]; then
    ngx_addon_name=ngx_http_geoip2_module
    HTTP_MODULES="$HTTP_MODULES ngx_http_geoip2_module"
    NGX_ADDON_SRCS="$NGX_ADDON_SRCS $ngx_addon_dir/ngx_http_geoip2_module.c"
    CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS -lmaxminddb"
else   
    cat << END
$0: error: the geoip2 module requires the maxminddb library.
END
    exit 1
fi
```

Does anyone know what may have gone wrong here?

UPDATE: some relevant output by `sh -x ./configure ..`:

```
+ echo adding module in /home/cilium/ngx_http_geoip2_module
adding module in /home/cilium/ngx_http_geoip2_module
+ test -f /home/cilium/ngx_http_geoip2_module/config
+ . /home/cilium/ngx_http_geoip2_module/config
+ ngx_feature=MaxmindDB library
+ ngx_feature_name=
+ ngx_feature_run=no
+ ngx_feature_incs=#include <maxminddb.h>
+ ngx_feature_libs=-lmaxminddb
+ . auto/feature
+ echo checking for MaxmindDB library ...\c
checking for MaxmindDB library ...+ cat
+ ngx_found=no
+ test -n

...

+ [ -x objs/autotest ]
+ echo  not found
 not found
+ echo ----------
+ cat objs/autotest.c
+ echo ----------
+ echo cc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/chromium/src -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/google-sparsehash/src -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/google-sparsehash/gen/arch/linux/x64/include -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/protobuf/src -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/re2/src -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/out/Debug/obj/gen -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/out/Debug/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/apr/src/include -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/aprutil/src/include -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/apr/gen/arch/linux/x64/include -I /home/cilium/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta/psol/include/third_party/aprutil/gen/arch/linux/x64/include -o objs/autotest objs/autotest.c -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -lmaxminddb
+ echo ----------
+ rm -rf objs/autotest.c
+ [ no = yes ]
+ cat
./configure: error: the geoip2 module requires the maxminddb library.
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Did the header get installed?

Comment: @o11c, missing headers sounds like a possibility. I just followed the installation guide. How do I find out if headers for a specific library exist?

Comment: `locate maxminddb.h` if you have your file database up-to-date, or `find /usr/local/include /usr/include -name maxminddb.h` if you don't. Most likely it would be in `/usr/local/include` since the libs were in local.

Comment: @o11c, thanks. The header file is installed, it is at: /usr/local/include/maxminddb.h. Strange, so what else could cause the problem?

Comment: @o11c, is it possible that the script only looks in `/usr/include` but not in `/usr/local/include`?

Comment: The configure script says that the *library* is not found, not that the *header* is not found. Look at the config.log file for the real error.

Comment: And in case the configure script doesn't put enough information in the config.log file, you can also run it with `sh -x ./configure` to trace the shell commands (this will give you a lot of output). Note that GCC (actually cpp) looks at `/usr/local/include` by default (see with `cpp -v /dev/null`).

Comment: @vinc17, I don't see `config.log` file anywhere. Is it the log file for the configure of `nginx` or something else? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @vinc17, and `sh -x ./configure ...` throws `sh: 0: Can't open ./configure`

Comment: @MLister `config.log` is the usual log file for `configure` scripts: if there is any error, you can get useful information there. When you run `sh -x ./configure ...`, are you sure that you are in the right directory (where the `configure` script is)? This is similar to `./configure ...` except that the shell is run with the `-x` flag.

Comment: @vinc17, I've searched the whole system, but cannot find `config.log` anywhere. Perhaps `nginx`'s configure does not produce such a log. On the other hand, I've managed to run the configure with `sh -x`, and I've added the relevant output to my original question above.

Comment: @MLister It appears that nginx's configure tests both the library and the header at the same time. Now, some important part is missing: one needs to know the error from `cc`. It wasn't visible in the `configure` output. So it must have been redirected to some file (`config.log` with most software, but it may have another name). Moreover the `cc` invocation itself doesn't appear in what you have quoted.

Comment: Are you also installing the pagespeed module? if yes, move the pagespeed argument to after this module's argument in the configure arguments. more [here](https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module/issues/10#issuecomment-58461914).

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the "devel" version of maxminddb, so I used:

```
yum install libmaxminddb-devel
```

Comment: debian: `sudo apt install libmaxminddb-dev`

Answer (score 2):

To anyone having this problem, here is the solution:

1. git clone --recursive https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb
2. cd libmaxminddb
3. ./bootstrap
4. ./configure
5. make
6. make install

I noticed that initially after cloning there was no configure executable, but after running ./bootstrap, **it got created**.
Then i run ./configure, make, make install, and then i noticed that within the folder `/usr/local/include` **maxminddb_config.h and maxminddb.h were created**.

Then i run my installation nginx script and there were no errors anymore.